# Ошибка unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Изучаю Hibernate и столкнулся с проблемой, по руководству всё сделал один в один, и все равно - ошибочка :(

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_basics_tutorial</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">former</property>
    <mapping class="com.valeobet.server.arbitrage.Artist"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Класс Artist (геттеры и сеттеры вставлять не буду)

```
@Entity
public class Artist {
    @Id
    private int id;
}
```

Вот метод, который вызывает ошибку

```
public Artist createArtist(int id, String name, String genre) {
    Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, genre);
    em.persist(artist); //<----- ЭТА СТРОКА ---------
    return artist;
}
```

Вот ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.valeobet.server.arbitrage.Artist
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:760)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:736)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:741)
at com.valeobet.server.arbitrage.ArtistService.createArtist(ArtistService.java:17)
at com.valeobet.server.arbitrage.HibernateBasicsTutorial.main(HibernateBasicsTutorial.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Структура проекта

[image: project structure java]

UPD:

```
public class ArtistService {

private EntityManager em;

public ArtistService(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public Artist createArtist(int id, String name, String genre) {
    Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, genre);
    em.persist(artist);
    return artist;
}

public void removeArtist(int id) {
    Artist artist = em.find(Artist.class, id);

    if (artist != null) {
        em.remove(artist);
    }
}

public Artist changeArtistGenre(int id, String genre) {
    Artist artist = em.find(Artist.class, id);

    if (artist != null) {
        artist.setGenre(genre);
    }

    return artist;
}

public Artist findArtist(int id) {
    return em.find(Artist.class, id);
}

public List<Artist> findAllArtists() {
    TypedQuery<Artist> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Artist a", Artist.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

UPD2:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
ArtistService service = new ArtistService(session);
```

Comment: А в классе Artist имя и жанр как объявлены и с какими аннотациями? В бд эта таблица уже есть?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim `private String name; private String genre;` аннотаций нет. Таблица есть

Comment: Покажите еще как строите `sessionFactory`. Точнее `em`. Чтоб понимать как у вас там устроено. Возможно ошибка еще там

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил в пост

Comment: @jessez не то. интересует именно `em`, т.е. `EntityManager`

Comment: Неее, он имел ввиду именно создание объекта EntityManager. В частности как настраиваете EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim понял, добавил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не правильно Вас понял, спать пора уже идти, да разобраться в проблеме хочу. Обновил пост

Comment: Честно, я сам не много могу посоветовать ибо маппинг делаю через xml. Но кстати у вас еще нет аннотации с именем таблицы. Добавил в свой ответ пример.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim тоже не помогло, пробовал, спасибо. Посплю и потом сяду курить другой мануал!

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim с названием таблицы тоже самое - необязательно))

Comment: @jessez честно говоря немного смущен. у вас что-то намешано.. есть hibernate.xml а еще persistense, для работы которого нужно максимум `EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyFactoryYO");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ArtistService service = new ArtistService(em);` ......в конструктор вы кидаете сессию `new ArtistService(session);` а в классе принимаете менеджера `ArtistService(EntityManager em)` ....... что за урок такой? где?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский persistance я удалил, лишний файлик, тестил. Полагаю, без него мне Ваш код уже не поможет? Иду спать, разберусь завтра ))

Comment: @jessez без `persistence` в `ArtistManager` будет немного по-другому все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, погуглил туториалы за 2015 год и в комментариях нашел решение. 
Строчка (в UPD2):

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

была заменена на:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

> private String name; private String genre; аннотаций нет.

Вот в том то и проблема, анотации должны быть ко ВСЕМ колонкам таблицы (и соответствующим переменным класса)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;
```

Вот пара более менее читабельных гайдов:

- [На русском](http://java-course.ru/old/students/students.php?name=part18)
- [На английском](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm)

Comment: Вы уверены? `@Column(name = "first_name")` обязательна если имя колонки в базе и в классе различаются. Разве нет?

Comment: Добавил аннотации, проблема не пропала.